# Cannot run diskutil, sudo or not

Tags: mac, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, disk-utility

I cannot run `diskutil` on my brand new Retina Macbook Pro 2012. When I try to run it, (including sudo), the terminal says "command not found". I looked in usr/bin and usr/sbin and could not find `diskutil`.

Am I looking in the wrong place for it, or are there deeper problems with my system?

Comment: It should be in `/usr/sbin/diskutil` by default. If you really need it, you could try doing an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition.

Comment: Well I tried but still nothing..
Can I download it somewhere ?